# Can i Extract and Re-deploy all custom solutions when i change the Default Zone URL in AAM

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping

I have plan to change the default zone URL for a SharePoint web application , and there are some farm solutions also deployed if I change the default zone URL
can I Extract and Re-deploy all custom solutions which are bonded to the old default zone URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to extract them and re-deploy. After you change zone the solution should be still available, solution are applied to Sharepoint Web App which is parent object for IIS Web App. All solution should propagate correctly (please note that if necessary most admins make changes to web.config files manually and those will not propagate when you extend web app, so make sure to make a backup copy of web config and compare them afterwards).

Never the less if you really need to you can always backup your solutions using this cmdlet:

```
Get-SpSolution | forEach-Object {
$_.SolutionFile.SaveAs("d:deploy\backup\$($_.Name)")}
```

This will save all your custom solutions.